# Проблема в коде JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
for (let i = 0; i < boldText; i++) {
  document.querySelector('#boldText')[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    firstBlock.style.fontWeight = '900' [i];
    boldText[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      firstBlock.style.fontWeight = '300' [i];
    })

  })
}
```

```html
<form name="fontStyleBlock">
  <p class="styleText">Style:</p>
  <input type="radio" name="fontStyle" id="boldText">Bold Text
</form>
```

Почему не работает данный код?
При клике на bold text текст в блоке должен становится жирным при повторном нажатии должен становится нормальным

Comment: Интересно, а `'300' [i]` вот это что должно было делать по задумке?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот код не работает, потому что в нем написана какая-то белиберда.

```js
var firstBlock = document.getElementById("firstBlock");
document.getElementById('boldText').addEventListener('click', function() {
  firstBlock.style.fontWeight = (firstBlock.style.fontWeight == '900')? '300' : '900';
});
```

```html
<form name="fontStyleBlock">
  <p class="styleText">Style:</p>
  <label><input type="radio" name="fontStyle" id="boldText">Bold Text</label>
</form>
<br/>
<div id="firstBlock">TEST</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Лучше подходит чекбокс, а не радиокнопка:

```js
const firstBlock = document.getElementById('first-block');
document.forms.styles.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  const st = firstBlock.style; 
  switch (target.name) {
    case 'bold': 
      st.fontWeight = target.checked ? 'bold' : 'normal';
      break; 
    case 'italic': 
      st.fontStyle = target.checked ? 'italic' : 'normal';
      break; 
    case 'underlined': 
      st.textDecoration = target.checked ? 'underline' : 'none';
      break; 
    /* ... */
  }
});
```

```html
<form name="styles">
  <p class="style-text">Text style:</p>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="bold">Bold</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="italic">Italic</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="underlined">Underlined</label>
</form>
<br>
<div id="first-block">TEST</div>
```

Ну и html-идентификаторы (айди, классы) хорошо бы в обычном `kebab-case` указывать :)