# Как сократить костыль? Как написать короче данный скрипт?

Tags: javascript, dom, инспекция-кода

Всем привет! Написал тут решение данной задачи, но мне кажется что это какой-то костыль. Если есть идеи, накидайте, пожалуйста. Дайте аргументы если где-то что-то коряво и или даже если нормально :). Вот сама задача и мое решение:

Дан абзац. Даны чекбоксы 'перечеркнуть', 'сделать жирным', 'сделать красным'. Если соответствующий чекбокс отмечен - заданное действие 
происходит с абзацем (становится красным, например). Если чекбоксу снять отметку - действие отменяется.

```js
let p = document.querySelector('p');
let checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('input');

for (let i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
  if (i === 0) {
    checkbox[i].addEventListener('click', changeTextDecoration);
  }
  if (i === 1) {
    checkbox[i].addEventListener('click', changeFontWeight);
  }
  if (i === 2) {
    checkbox[i].addEventListener('click', changeColor);
  }
}

function changeTextDecoration() {
  if (this.checked) {
    p.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
  } else {
    p.style.textDecoration = 'none';
  }
}

function changeFontWeight() {
  if (this.checked) {
    p.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
  } else {
    p.style.fontWeight = 'normal';
  }
}

function changeColor() {
  if (this.checked) {
    p.style.color = 'red';
  } else {
    p.style.color = 'black';
  }
}
```

```html
<p> Paragraph </p>
<input type="checkbox"> Перечеркнуть
<input type="checkbox"> Сделать полужирным
<input type="checkbox"> Сделать красным
```

Comment: 1) Избавиться от цикла for, он тут не нужен; 2) Использовать тернарный оператор

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1058421/288409

Comment: так много ответов, всем по плюсу

Answer (score 7):

Как-нибудь так, например.

```js
let p = document.querySelector('p');
let checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('input');
    
for ( let i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++ ){
     checkbox[i].addEventListener('click', cbClick);        
}

function cbClick(){        
    const cfg = {
            strike: { p: 'textDecoration', v: 'line-through', d: 'none' },
            bold:   { p: 'fontWeight',     v: 'bold',         d: 'normal'},
            red:    { p: 'color',          v: 'red',          d: 'black'} 
          };
        
    const x = cfg[this.dataset.type];        
        
    p.style[x.p] = this.checked ? x.v : x.d;
};
```

```html
<p> Paragraph </p>
    <input type="checkbox" data-type="strike"> Перечеркнуть
    <input type="checkbox" data-type="bold"> Сделать полужирным
    <input type="checkbox" data-type="red"> Сделать красным
```

Answer (score 1):

или так, например

```js
const p = document.querySelector('p'),
  checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('input'),
  changeTextDecoration = e => p.style.textDecoration = e.target.checked ? 'line-through' : 'none',
  changeFontWeight = e => p.style.fontWeight = e.target.checked ? 'bold' : 'normal',
  changeColor = e => p.style.color = e.target.checked ? 'red' : 'black'

checkbox[0].addEventListener('click', changeTextDecoration)
checkbox[1].addEventListener('click', changeFontWeight)
checkbox[2].addEventListener('click', changeColor)
```

```html
<p>AHAHAHA</p>
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: Обычно считается не очень хорошей практикой объединять объявления переменных в одном выражении, лучше разделять, для лучшей читаемости

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin писать код,зависимый от позиции элемента на странице, тоже так себе, но вас это не остановило )

Comment: в условии позиция, ниче не знаю, не мое)

Answer (score 1):

```js
let p = document.querySelector('p');
let checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('input');

checkbox[0].addEventListener('click', changeTextDecoration);
checkbox[1].addEventListener('click', changeFontWeight);
checkbox[2].addEventListener('click', changeColor);

function changeTextDecoration() {
  p.style.textDecoration = this.checked ? 'line-through' : 'none';
}

function changeFontWeight() {
  p.style.fontWeight = this.checked ? 'bold' : 'normal';
}

function changeColor() {
  p.style.color = this.checked ? 'red' : 'black';
}
```

```html
<p> Paragraph </p>
<input type="checkbox"> Перечеркнуть
<input type="checkbox"> Сделать полужирным
<input type="checkbox"> Сделать красным
```

P.S.Пока писал увидел сообщение от [Андрей NOP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/218063/%d0%90%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9-nop), это сообщение является его реализацией

Answer (score 1):

Это ваш базовый вариант

```js
let p = document.querySelector('p');
let checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('input');

const listeners = [
  changeTextDecoration,
  changeFontWeight,
  changeColor
];
for (let i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
  checkbox[i].addEventListener('click', listeners[i]);
}

function changeTextDecoration() {
  p.style.textDecoration = (this.checked) ? 'line-through' : 'none';
}

function changeFontWeight() {
  p.style.fontWeight = (this.checked) ? 'bold' : 'normal';
}

function changeColor() {
  p.style.color = (this.checked) ? 'red' : 'black';
}
```

```html
<p> Paragraph </p>
<input type="checkbox"> Перечеркнуть
<input type="checkbox"> Сделать полужирным
<input type="checkbox"> Сделать красным
```

Но идея тупо перебирать в цикле элементы и назначать по порядку обработчики опасна. В середине добавится еще один инпут и все пропало.

Лучше их как-то проидентифицировать

```js
let p = document.querySelector('p');
let checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('input');

const listeners = {
  decor: changeTextDecoration,
  weight: changeFontWeight,
  color: changeColor
};

for (let i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
  const input = checkbox[i];
  input.addEventListener('click', listeners[input.getAttribute('data-id')]);
}

function changeTextDecoration() {
  p.style.textDecoration = (this.checked) ? 'line-through' : 'none';
}

function changeFontWeight() {
  p.style.fontWeight = (this.checked) ? 'bold' : 'normal';
}

function changeColor() {
  p.style.color = (this.checked) ? 'red' : 'black';
}
```

```html
<p> Paragraph </p>
<input type="checkbox" data-id="decor"> Перечеркнуть
<input type="checkbox" data-id="weight"> Сделать полужирным
<input type="checkbox" data-id="color"> Сделать красным
```

Или, учитывая тот факт, что каждый чекбокс включает или выключает какой-то элемент стиля, то можно обойтись одним обработчиком

```js
let p = document.querySelector('p');
let checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('input');

for (let i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
  const input = checkbox[i];
  input.addEventListener('click', change);
}

function change() {
  const attr = (this.checked) ? 'data-checked' : 'data-unchecked';
  p.style[this.getAttribute('data-style')] = this.getAttribute(attr)
}
```

```html
<p> Paragraph </p>
<input type="checkbox" data-style="textDecoration" data-checked="line-through" data-unchecked="none"> Перечеркнуть
<input type="checkbox" data-style="fontWeight" data-checked="bold" data-unchecked="normal"> Сделать полужирным
<input type="checkbox" data-style="color" data-checked="red" data-unchecked="black"> Сделать красным
```

Или вынести изменения в отдельные CSS классы и управлять самими классами

```js
let p = document.querySelector('p');
let checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('input');

for (let i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
  const input = checkbox[i];
  input.addEventListener('click', change);
}

function change() {
  const className = this.getAttribute('data-class');
  if (this.checked)
    p.classList.add(className);
  else
    p.classList.remove(className);
}
```

```css
.decor {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.weight {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.color {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p> Paragraph </p>
<input type="checkbox" data-class="decor"> Перечеркнуть
<input type="checkbox" data-class="weight"> Сделать полужирным
<input type="checkbox" data-class="color"> Сделать красным
```

Answer (score 1):

## немного магии и `custom elements`

- `custom elements`
  расширение базовых `html` элементов, например:

  ```
  class XDiv extends HTMLElement {}
  customElements.define('x-div', XDiv)
  ```
- `ShadowRoot`
  грубо говоря - упрощённая версия `iframe`, например: можно не париться с `id`

---

### обратите внимание на проброс стилей и чекбоксов в примере

```js
// @ts-check
class XDiv extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    /** @type {ShadowRoot} */
    let shadowRoot;
    try { shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'closed' }) } catch (e) { return; }
    shadowRoot.appendChild(document.createRange().createContextualFragment(`
      <slot></slot>
      <p id="p">Paragraph</p>
    `))
    shadowRoot.addEventListener('change', e => {
      const { dataset, checked } = e.target;
      if (!dataset.class) return;
      const p = shadowRoot.getElementById('p')
      if (checked) p.classList.add(dataset.class)
      else p.classList.remove(dataset.class)
    })
    Array.from(this.getElementsByTagName('style'), el => {
      shadowRoot.appendChild(el)
    })
  }
}
customElements.define('x-div', XDiv)
```

```html
<x-div>
  <style>
    .strike {
      text-decoration: line-through;
    }

    .bold {
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .red {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-class="strike" />Перечеркнуть</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-class="bold" />Сделать полужирным</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-class="red" />Сделать красным</label>
</x-div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<p id="p"> Paragraph </p>
<input type="checkbox" s="text-decoration=line-through"> Перечеркнуть
<input type="checkbox" s="font-weight=bold"> Сделать полужирным
<input type="checkbox" s="color=red"> Сделать красным

<script>
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(
    document.querySelectorAll('input'),
    (i) => i.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
      let s = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('s').split('=')
      p.style[s[0]] = e.currentTarget.checked ? s[1] : ''
    })
  )
</script>
```